# How to reuse an IMFSample without consuming additional memory

Tags: c++, video, memory-management, ms-media-foundation, screen-capture

I wrote a screen video capture program in C++ /CLI. I capture the video 30 times a second and display it in a picture box. My idea was to copy the IMFSample to a reusable output sample then free the source sample to control memory usage.

Although I call sampleOut->RemoveAllBuffers() prior to sampleOut->AddBuffer(destBuf), it still consumes additional memory. It appears that RemoveAllBuffers doesn't actually free the memory from the prior video frame. Any idea how I can free the memory without having to release the sampleOut and recreate it?

```
HRESULT ScreenCapture::DuplicateSample(IMFSample* sample)
{       
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    if (!sample)
    {
        hr = E_ABORT;
        return hr;
    }
            
    DWORD sampleFlags = 0;
    LONGLONG llVideoTimeStamp = 0;
    LONGLONG llSampleDuration = 0;
    IMFMediaBuffer* srcBuf;
    IMFMediaBuffer* destBuf;

    hr = sample->GetSampleFlags(&sampleFlags);
    hr = sample->GetSampleTime(&llVideoTimeStamp);
    hr = sample->GetSampleDuration(&llSampleDuration);

    hr = sampleOut->SetSampleFlags(sampleFlags);
    hr = sampleOut->SetSampleTime(llVideoTimeStamp);
    hr = sampleOut->SetSampleDuration(llSampleDuration);

    srcBuf = nullptr;
    hr = sample->GetBufferByIndex(0, &srcBuf);

    byte* srcByteBuffer = nullptr;
    DWORD srcBuffCurrLen = 0;
    DWORD srcBuffMaxLen = 0;

    hr = srcBuf->Lock(&srcByteBuffer, &srcBuffMaxLen, &srcBuffCurrLen);

    destBuf = nullptr;
    hr = MFCreateMemoryBuffer(srcBuffCurrLen, &destBuf);

    byte* destByteBuffer = nullptr;

    hr = destBuf->Lock(&destByteBuffer, nullptr, nullptr);

    memcpy(destByteBuffer, srcByteBuffer, srcBuffCurrLen);

    hr = destBuf->Unlock();
    hr = srcBuf->Unlock();

    hr = destBuf->SetCurrentLength(srcBuffCurrLen);

    SafeRelease(&srcBuf);

    sampleOut->RemoveAllBuffers();
    hr = sampleOut->AddBuffer(destBuf); //Memory issue here

    SafeRelease(&destBuf);

    return hr;
}
```

As you can see I also need a better way to handle the hr testing for each step. I figured I deal with that after I get the code working.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but you should use smart pointers technology (ATL, WRL, WIL, C++/WinRT are fine). This will at least ensure you release memory also in case of failure, plus it simplify codes and removes the number of code lines (SafeRelease). For error management, these frameworks usually propose facilities too, for example with WIL https://github.com/microsoft/wil/wiki/Error-handling-helpers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you are interested in is how to reuse samples instead of allocating them each time. The primary call you want to avoid is `MFCreateMemoryBuffer` because it is the actual memory consumer, not the buffer attachment/detachment from sample objects.

The ideal solution is along these lines:

- you create a memory allocator (conceptually similar to created by [`MFCreateVideoSampleAllocatorEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfapi/nf-mfapi-mfcreatevideosampleallocatorex), just your own implementation)
- the allocator manages a pool of samples, either pre-created or extended on demand
- your code obtains a sample with respective buffer from memory allocator and before the same is fully released, which you track by looking at COM reference count of the object that implements `IMFSample`, it is considered as engaged and is not available for reuse from the pool
- once everyone releases a sample, it returns to the pool and is available for reuse; that is, your video frame processing code will not allocate any new buffers, it will pick next free buffer which is already allocated and available

This is exactly how allocators provided by mentioned `MFCreateVideoSampleAllocatorEx` work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I haven't written the sink that will save the video to a file yet, so I can't release any of the video frames. It looks like I'll have to do that before I can manage the memory as you describe.